# xcode - decode xml output string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, xcode, decode

```
NSString *col1 = [aBook.name stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" \n\t"]];

NSLog(@"column1: %@", col1); //output:-  ABC+Company
```

This is my xml data output. 
It comes with '+' mark. How can i decode this?
Could you please help me?

Comment: Please mark as the correct answer if it helped you (by clicking on the checkmark on the left of the answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also replace the plus signs with spaces, if that’s what you’re after:

```
NSString *name = [col1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@" "];
```

Answer (score 2):

You mean get the parts that are seperated by the '+' sign? You can do that with:

```
NSArray *stringArray = [col1 componentsSeparatedByString:@"+"];

[stringArray objectAtIndex:0]; //ABC
[stringArray objectAtIndex:1]; //Company
```

If you want to remove/replace the '+' sign you can do this:

```
NSString* string = [col1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@""]; //last string can be empty or have a string value
```

Hope this helped you!